# Prove that if $T$ is a tree of order at least $4$ that is not a star then $T$ complement contains a Hamilton path.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that if $T$ is a tree of order at least $4$ that is not a star then $T$ complement contains a Hamilton path.

I am not sure how to start this one. Every tree has a unique path from one vertex to another and does not have cycles.

Comment: Do you understand what is meant by T-complement? Can you work out how many edges it has?

Comment: The complement of a graph I think it the verticies that are not connected in the original graph are connected and the ones that are a disconnected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to prove this is by induction on $\lvert T\rvert$.

For the inductive step, remove a leaf node $v$ from $T$ to get a new tree that contains one less element.  As long as that new tree is not a star, we know that its complement contains a Hamilton path; and, because $v$ can't have possibly been connected to both ends of this path in $T$ (because it has degree $1$), we can extend that path to a Hamilton path on all of $T$.

Of course, that only works if $T\setminus v$ is not a star. Can you prove that if $T$ is not a star and $\lvert T\rvert>4$, then there is a leaf node $v$ such that $T\setminus v$ is not a star?

Comment: how do you know the complement has a hamilton path.

Comment: That's the inductive hypothesis.  We assume we've already proved the result for trees of size $n$ that aren't stars; now, we're trying to prove that it holds for trees of size $n+1$ that aren't stars.  When we removed the leaf, we got a new non-star tree of size $n$.

Comment: Ok I guess it makes sense

Comment: So we know T-v has a Hamilton path add v and it has degree one we get a new path ending at v